# ¿Cómo poner varios layouts en la configuración de Sonata?

Tags: symfony2

```
sonata_admin:
templates:
    dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
    user_block: FooBundle:Block:user_block.html.twig
    layout:   FooBundle::layout.html.twig
```

¿Cómo puedo poner varios layouts? En cuanto pongo otro da error.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar esta configuración:

```yml
templates: {dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig, user_block: FooBundle:Block:user_block.html.twig, layout: FooBundle::layout.html.twig, other: OtherBundle::layout.html.twig}
```

[más detalles aquí](https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot's-introduction-to-yaml)